# Why does my checkbox have no value after spending with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple function that looks like this:

```
function addCheckbox(name, id) {
  var container = $('#activitiesList');
  $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: id, name: 'activities[]' }).appendTo(container);
  $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name}).appendTo(container);
  alert($('#cb'+ id).val());
}
```

The value gets properly alerted there.  But when I go inspect the element in the browser it looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="" name="activities[]">
```

I have searched and there is no other references to that container.  So something magically is stripping out the value. Because when the form gets submitted there is no value there either.

**UPDATE**

Problem was caused by wrong selector name and it is fixed now.

Comment: create jsfiddle plz

Comment: The main questions is if you really need to keep the state in DOM. This is not a very good practice.

Comment: Working fine.... https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/zf0xoa7a/

Answer (score 0):

Answer is... I am an idiot.  I had a errant selector doing this later down the line.  My apologies everyone.